# shake dependency flutter package not working

Tags: android, flutter

my code giving me this error.
D/SensorManager( 2702): unregisterListener ::
D/SensorManager( 2702): registerListener :: 0, BMA254 Acceleration Sensor, 200000, 0,

my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shake/shake.dart';

class DemoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoPageState createState() => _DemoPageState();
}

class _DemoPageState extends State<DemoPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ShakeDetector detector = ShakeDetector.autoStart(
      onPhoneShake: () {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text('Shake!'),
          ),
        );
        print('shake');
        // Do stuff on phone shake
      },
      minimumShakeCount: 1,
      shakeSlopTimeMS: 500,
      shakeCountResetTime: 3000,
      shakeThresholdGravity: 2.7,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('demo'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what device are you using to test?

Comment: an android phone, not emulator